# the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found calling rest api through python

Tags: java, json, python-3.x, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to call spring boot rest api through python script. To consume multipart/form-data or MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, I have written a json file in which all content is passed include java POJO, headers and some other content, but while calling it through Python, I am getting below error message

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.handleParseFailure(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
```

```java
// Spring rest api which is calling from Python
 
    @Override
    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestParam("EmployeeDTO") EmployeeDTO req, HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response) {}
```

Request parameters are passed through json file whose structure is like:

```json
[
  {
    "part_name": "EmployeeDTO",
    "part_content": {
        "empName": "XYZ",
        "empId": "1234",
        "dept": "Engineering"
      },
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "multipart/form-data",
      "Accept-Encoding": "utf-8, gzip, deflate, br",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
    },
  {
    "part_name": "request",
    "part_content": {
      "It can be any kind of data": "String, JSON, XML,etc"
    }
  }
]
```

Python script calling rest api by using:

```py
r = requests.request(method.lower(), host_url, headers=headers, data=body, verify=False)
```

Please let me know if needs more details.

Answer (score 0):

Input parameters should be passed like below in the python script:

```
# get input file extension using below command:
fileType = mimetypes.guess_type('absolute path of input file')[0] or 'application/octet-stream'
# Define input files passed for Multipart Input parameter in POST API.
files=[
   ('EmployeeDTO',('InputFile.ext',open('absolute path of input file','rb'),fileType)),
   ('request',('InputFile.ext',open('absolute path of input file','rb'), fileType))
 ]
# call POST API using below command
r = requests.request(method.lower(), host_url, headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)
# here method=POST, host_url=https://localhost:8443/rest/api, headers=[{'content-type':'application/json'}], multiple headers can be added like this.
```

Here EmployeeDTO is the first input parameter which can be any name given to the passed object. InputFile.ext is the Json file mentioned above and ext is the type of the InputFile, it can be json, XML, HTML etc. "absolute path of input file" is the path of the InputFile.ext like temp/EmployeeInput.json. 'rb' is read file in bytes format. 'fileType' is the extension of the InputFile.

request is same as EmployeeDTO. It is the second file passed to POST API. Similarly we can pass any number of input files for Multipart file.